# How to .htacces redirect subfolder to another subfolder without changing url in browserbar

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm stuck in htaccess, again! (not my strongest skill) ;-)

How do I redirect:

**www.domain.com/folder1**

to:

**www.domain.com/folder2/something/**

Without changing the url in the browserbar? (so keep displaying www.domain.com/folder1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# externally redirect requests made for folder2/something
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+folder2/something/
RewriteRule ^ /folder1 [L,R=301]

# internally rewrite the request back to /folder2/something/
RewriteRule ^folder1 /folder2/something/ [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! But for some reason this breaks the whole css etc. as well. Those (css/js/image) files get redirected to the wrong folder now.

Comment: @user2987394 probably because you have relative URLs and that breaks if you change the URI base like you're doing. Change them all to absolute URLs for you css/js/images.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's correct, I use relative URLs. Hmm, so there is no other solution than change all my assets to absolute URLs? That's not very ideal.

Comment: By the way, technically it is unnecessary to direct www.domain.com/folder2/something/ to www.domain.com/folder1, so doesn't leaving this part out solve the issue above? Or is this impossible?

Comment: @user2987394 you can leave it out, that rule is added just in case you have the old URL out in the wild and you want it to look canonical

Comment: Sorry, I just don't get it to work, what is the part I can leave out? 'Cause whatever I do it breaks.

Comment: @user2987394 "**so doesn't leaving this part out solve the issue above?**" the "this part" I assumed you meant the 2 lines under the `# externally redirect requests made for folder2/something`

Comment: Yes, thats what I did now, I used just the `RewriteRule ^folder1 /folder2/something/ [L]`. That works, but still with the broken css/js/images etc.

Comment: Like I said, you have to either use absolute urls because you've changed the URI base, or use something like `<base href="/" />` in your page header

Comment: **"so doesn't leaving this part out solve the issue above?"** So I assumed that will solve the issue, but it didn't. Base href did, of course! Thanks.